# Implementing javascript events to Wicket

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, slider, wicket

I'm new to ria-development and working with the [Ajax Slider example](http://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/source/browse/tags/jqwicket-demo-0.4/jqwicket-demo/src/main/java/net/javaforge/jqwicket/SliderPage.java). I can't figure out how to work with javascript events. Here in the example the onValueChanged-event is preimplemented. How do I implement say onchange- or onSlider-event?

All help greatly appreciated!

```
public abstract class AjaxSlider extends WebMarkupContainer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AjaxSlider(String id) {
            super(id);
            super.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    }
    public JQUIComponentBehaivor<SliderOptions> getSlideBehaviors() {
        List behaviors = getBehaviors();
        for(Object behavior : behaviors){
            if(behavior instanceof SliderBehavior)
                        return (SliderBehavior) behavior;
        }
        return null;
    }


    public abstract void onValueChanged(AjaxRequestTarget target,
                    int newValue);

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
            super.onInitialize();
            AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior =
                new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                            String sliderValue = RequestCycle.get().getRequest()
                                            .getParameter("sv");
                            if (Utils.isNotBlank(sliderValue)) {
                                    onValueChanged(target, Integer.valueOf(sliderValue));
                            }
                    }
            };
            super.add(ajaxBehavior);
            super.add(new SliderBehavior(new SliderOptions()
                            .changeEvent(wicketAjaxGet(
                                            ajaxBehavior,
                                            new MapBuilder<String, Object>().add("sv",
                                                            js("ui.value")).build()))));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you gave adds an event handler for the change event. What this event handler does is issueing a GET request to the `ajaxBehavior`defined above. The behavior then extracts the slider value from the GET parameters and calls `onValueChanged`.

You can add another event handler just like this to `SliderOptions`. For instance:

```
.slideEvent(
    wicketAjaxGet(ajaxBehavior,
                  new MapBuilder<String, Object>()
                  .add("sv",  js("ui.value")).build()))));
```

This handler should call the ajax behavior any time the user moves the slider.

Comment: +1 for your answer, but please indent your code the next time. BTW, for a map with a single entry you might want to use [Collections.singletonMap(kay, value)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap%28K%2C%20V%29) .

Comment: Oh, I just realized that the MapBuilder code is the OP's own. Never mind.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, now how do I separate the events? Now I'm getting both of the events to the respond-method.

Comment: You could deal with both events in a single response method, i.e. not passing the query parameter "sv" in both cases but something different for change and slide. Alternatively you can add a second `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior`and pass this new behavor to the slideEvent method.