# Sending file array from js to java using wicket ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket, wicket-6

I'm load multiple file list using field input of type file. Problem is i want to delete some of them from original list before form post. Couse FileList is immutable in js and I can't create new input to post with overridden FileList (js security reasons) I must build array with files that I want to submit.

But i don't know how to post and receive it using Wicket.Ajax.post (due to the above-mentioned I can't post form)

Standard fileUploadField get request as instance of IMultipartWebRequest on form post. How to do same using Wicket.Ajax.post ?

Comment: Hi Mr Jedi, were you able to solve the problem described here? I am in the same situation: I want to delete a specific file from the file list if I uploaded multiple files at once/in one file input field. The 'MultiFileUploadField' provided in Wicket 6.x deletes all files if they were selected together, which isn't what I want.
Because I'm making a kind of plugin to existing software I'm not able to upgrade Wicket to a newer version, nor can I mount a resource in the Wicket application.

Comment: @Vertongen As far as I remember I used some kind of jQuery uploder plugin and do some tricks with hidden inputs to send those files with form. But I'm not sure, it was some time ago and I don't have project sources.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. To bad you don't have the sources any more. I'll keep at it and post an answer when I found it.

Answer (score 0):

Wicket.Ajax.post() is a wrapper for http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.
It just gives you hooks where you can manipulate the request or response: onBefore, onPrecondition, onSuccess, etc.
So if you find a way to do what you need with plain jQuery then just add this logic in onBeforeSend hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can already do this my using a MultiFileUpload? You don't need to build it yourself.

See this Wicket example:
http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/upload/multi

Comment: I can't couse I can't delete one file from list if I upload X files at once. It provide delete all files but not one (if they where selected together)

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation: I wanted to delete a specific file from the file list when I uploaded multiple files at once/in one file input field. The 'MultiFileUploadField' provided in Wicket 6.x deletes all files if they were selected together, which isn't what I want. Because I'm making a kind of plugin to existing software I'm not able to upgrade Wicket to a newer version, nor can I mount a resource in the Wicket application.

Mr Jedi mentioned in the comments:

> As far as I remember I used some kind of jQuery uploder plugin and do some tricks with hidden inputs to send those files with form. But I'm not sure, it was some time ago and I don't have project sources.

My solution isn't complete yet and doesn't use an upload plugin (yet?). It can be used as a 'base' for means to upload files to a Wicket application with JavaScript.
The critical component is the added *ajaxBehavior* which receives a *FormData object* which was submitted by *jQuery.ajax()*.

*A word of caution*  I use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to POST data to the Wicket application, without fallback.
This might not work in older browsers. Check [jQuery browser support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) for more information.
Also note that [FormData objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) are not fully supported by all browsers yet.

First I extended the existing MultiFileUploadField:

```
public class MyMultiFileUploadField extends MultiFileUploadField {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final ResourceReference JS = new JavaScriptResourceReference(
                    MyMultiFileUploadField.class, "MyMultiFileUploadField.js");

    private final WebComponent upload;
    private final WebMarkupContainer container;
    private final AbstractAjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior;

    private final String componentIdPrefix;
    private final int maxUploads;
    private final boolean useMultipleAttr;
```

We provide our own constructor where we add ajaxBehavior to the component:

```
public MyMultiFileUploadField(String id, IModel<? extends Collection<FileUpload>> model, int max,
                    boolean useMultipleAttr) {
        super(id, model, max);

        this.maxUploads = max;
        this.useMultipleAttr = useMultipleAttr;

        upload = (WebComponent) get("upload"); // Created by parent as: new WebComponent("upload");
        container = (WebMarkupContainer) get("container"); // Created by parent as: new WebMarkupContainer("container");

        ajaxBehavior = new MyMultiFileUploadBehavior();
        add(ajaxBehavior);
    }
```

Also override the renderHead method so we can render our own JavaScript.
Important here is that we provide the `ajaxBehavior.getCallbackUrl()` to the script.

```
 @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(JS));
        response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("new MultiFileUpload('" + getInputName() + "', document.getElementById('"
                        + container.getMarkupId() + "'), " + maxUploads + ", " + useMultipleAttr + ", '" + ajaxBehavior.getCallbackUrl()
                        + "').addElement(document.getElementById('" + upload.getMarkupId() + "'));"));
    } // new MultiFileUpload(uploadFieldName, uploadContainer, maxUploads, useMultipleAttr, callbackUrl).addElement(fileInput);
```

The ajaxBehavior will receive the files and pass them to a FileHandler class for saving.
Many thanks to David Tanzer for explaining this in his post [jQuery Wicket](http://www.davidtanzer.net/jquery_wicket).

```
import org.apache.wicket.behavior.AbstractAjaxBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.upload.FileUpload;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.MultipartServletWebRequest;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebRequest;
import org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle;
import org.apache.wicket.request.handler.TextRequestHandler;
import org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Bytes;
import org.apache.wicket.util.upload.FileItem;
import org.apache.wicket.util.upload.FileUploadException;

public class MyMultiFileUploadBehavior extends AbstractAjaxBehavior {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onRequest() {
        final RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
        readRequest(requestCycle);
        sendResponse(requestCycle);
    }

    private void readRequest(final RequestCycle requestCycle) {
        Map<String, List<FileItem>> multiPartRequestFiles = null;

        final ServletWebRequest webRequest = (ServletWebRequest) requestCycle.getRequest();

        try {
            MultipartServletWebRequest multiPartRequest = webRequest.newMultipartWebRequest(Bytes.megabytes(1), "UploadInfo");
            multiPartRequest.parseFileParts();
            multiPartRequestFiles = multiPartRequest.getFiles();
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            return;
        }

        if (multiPartRequestFiles != null && !multiPartRequestFiles.isEmpty()) {
            for (Entry<String, List<FileItem>> entry : multiPartRequestFiles.entrySet()) {
                // For debug: iterate over the map and print a list of filenames
                final String name = entry.getKey();
                System.out.println("Entry name: '" + name + "'");

                final List<FileItem> fileItems = entry.getValue();
                for (FileItem file : fileItems) {
                    System.out.println("Entry file: '" + file.getName() + "'");
                }

                List<FileUpload> fileUploads = buildFileUploadList(fileItems);
                FileUploadForm.getUploadFileHandler().persistFiles(fileUploads);
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendResponse(final RequestCycle requestCycle) {
        requestCycle.scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(
            new TextRequestHandler("application/json", "UTF-8", "[]"));
    }

    private List<FileUpload> buildFileUploadList(List<FileItem> fileItems) {
        List<FileUpload> fileUploads = new ArrayList<>(fileItems.size());
        for (FileItem fileItem : fileItems) {
            fileUploads.add(new FileUpload(fileItem));
        }
        return fileUploads;
    }
}
```

You can persist the files the same way as shown in the [Wicket Examples](http://examples6x.wicket.apache.org/upload/multi) (also mentioned by RobAU).

As for the JavaScript I based myself on the script shipped with Wicket 6.x made by Stickman. Please note that this script is still very basic.
More details on [using wicket abstractajaxbehavior with jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976244/).
More information about [sending multipart formdata with jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/).

```
    /**
     * @author Stickman -- http://the-stickman.com
     * @author Vertongen
     * @see /org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/upload/MultiFileUploadField.js
     */
function MultiFileUpload(uploadFieldName, uploadContainer, maxUploads, useMultipleAttr, callbackUrl) {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Params: " + uploadFieldName+ ", " + uploadContainer + ", " + maxUploads + ", " + useMultipleAttr + ", " + callbackUrl);

    // Is there a maximum?
    if (!maxUploads) {
        maxUploads = -1;
    }
    // Map to hold selected files. Key is formatted as: 'upload_' + uploadId
    var formDataMap = new Map();
    //this.formDataMap = formDataMap;
    var uploadId = 0;
    // Reference to the file input element
    var fileInputElement = null;

    /**
     * Add a new file input element
     */
    this.addElement = function(fileInput) {
        // Make sure it's a file input element
        if (fileInput.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input' && fileInput.type.toLowerCase() === 'file') {

            if (useMultipleAttr) {
                fileInput.multiple = useMultipleAttr;
                if (Wicket && Wicket.Browser.isOpera()) {
                    // in Opera 12.02, changing 'multiple' this way
                    // does not update the field
                    fileInput.type = 'button';
                    fileInput.type = 'file';
                }
            }

            // Keep a reference to this MultiFileUpload object
            fileInput.multiFileUpload = this;
            // Keep a reference to the file input element
            fileInputElement = fileInput;

            // What to do when a file is selected
            fileInput.onchange = function() {
                // Check to see if we don't exceed the max.
                if (maxUploads !== -1) {
                    if (this.files.length > maxUploads) {
                        console.warn("More files selected than allowed!");
                        this.value = "";
                        return;
                    }
                    if((this.files.length + formDataMap.size) > maxUploads) {
                        console.warn("Total amount of files for upload exceeds the maximum!");
                        this.value = "";
                        return;
                    }
                }

                // Put selected files in the FormDataMap
                for (var i = 0, numFiles = this.files.length; i < numFiles; i++) {
                    uploadId++;
                    var fileId = "upload_" + uploadId;
                    var fileObj = this.files[i];

                    formDataMap.set(fileId, fileObj);
                    // Update uploadContainer add filenames to the list
                    this.multiFileUpload.addFileToUploadContainer(fileId, fileObj);
                }

                // Clear file input
                this.value = "";

                // If we've reached maximum number, disable file input element
                if (maxUploads !== -1 && formDataMap.size >= maxUploads) {
                    this.disabled = true;
                }           
            };          
        } else if (Wicket && Wicket.Log) {
            Wicket.Log.error('Error: not a file input element');
        }
    };

    this.addFileToUploadContainer = function(fileId, fileObj) {
        // Row div
        var new_row = document.createElement('tr');
        var contentsColumn = document.createElement('td');
        var buttonColumn = document.createElement('td');

        // Delete button
        var new_row_button = document.createElement('input');
        new_row_button.id = fileId;
        new_row_button.type = 'button';
        new_row_button.value = 'Remove';

        // Delete function
        new_row_button.onclick = function() {
            // Remove the selected file from the formData map.
            formDataMap.delete(this.id);

            // Remove this row from the list
            this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);

            // Re-enable file input element (if it's disabled)
            fileInputElement.disabled = false;

            // Appease Safari
            //    without it Safari wants to reload the browser window
            //    which nixes your already queued uploads
            return false;
        };

        // Add filename and button to row
        contentsColumn.innerHTML = this.getOnlyFileName(fileObj.name);
        new_row.appendChild(contentsColumn);
        new_row_button.style.marginLeft = '20px';
        buttonColumn.appendChild(new_row_button);
        new_row.appendChild(buttonColumn);

        uploadContainer.appendChild(new_row);
    };

    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitUploads');
    var resetButton = document.getElementById('resetUploads');

    var success = function() {console.log('success!'); };
    var failure = function() {console.log('failure.'); };
    var complete = function() {console.log('Done.'); };

    submitButton.onclick = function() {
        if(!formDataMap || formDataMap.size < 1) {
            console.warn("No files selected, cancelled upload!");
            return;
        }

        // Convert the Map into a FormData object.
        var formData = new FormData();
        formDataMap.forEach(function(value, key) {
              console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
              formData.append("uploads", value);
        });

        // Send the FormData object to our Wicket app.
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: callbackUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            context: self,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: [success],
            error: [failure],
            // complete: [complete]
        });
    };

    resetButton.onclick = function() {
        formDataMap.clear();
        fileInputElement.disabled = false;
    };

    this.getOnlyFileName = function(file) {
        var toEscape = {
            "&" : "&amp;",
            "<" : "&lt;",
            ">" : "&gt;",
            '"' : '&quot;',
            "'" : '&#39;'
        };

        function replaceChar(ch) {
            return toEscape[ch] || ch;
        }

        function htmlEscape(fileName) {
            return fileName.replace(/[&<>'"]/g, replaceChar);
        }

        var separatorIndex1 = file.lastIndexOf('\\');
        var separatorIndex2 = file.lastIndexOf('/');
        separatorIndex1 = Math.max(separatorIndex1, separatorIndex2);
        var fileName = separatorIndex1 >= 0 ? file.slice(separatorIndex1 + 1, file.length) : file;
        fileName = htmlEscape(fileName);
        return fileName;
    };
}
```

<del>The JavaScript isn't completely tested yet. I will post updates of the script when I find issues.</del>

You may also want to add a copy the HTML for the MultiFileUploadField.

```
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <input wicket:id="upload" type="file" class="wicket-mfu-field" />
    <div wicket:id="container" class="wicket-mfu-container">
        <div wicket:id="caption" class="wicket-mfu-caption"></div>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

For using the `MyMultiFileUploadField` class you can look at the [Wicket Examples](http://examples6x.wicket.apache.org/upload/multi) (also mentioned by RobAU). This code and HTML below is based on the Wicket Examples.

```
// collection that will hold uploaded FileUpload objects
private final Collection<FileUpload> uploads = new ArrayList<>();

public FileUploadForm(String formId, MultiUploadConfig multiUploadConfig) {
        super(formId);

        // set this form to multipart mode (always needed for uploads!)
        setMultiPart(true);

        // Add one multi-file upload field with this class attribute "uploads" as model
        multiFileUploadField = new MyMultiFileUploadField("fileInput",
                        new PropertyModel<Collection<FileUpload>>(this, "uploads"),
                        multiUploadConfig.getMaxNumberOfFiles(), true);
        add(multiFileUploadField);

        // Set the maximum size for uploads
        setMaxSize(Bytes.megabytes(multiUploadConfig.getMaxUploadSize()));

        // Set maximum size of each file in upload request
        setFileMaxSize(Bytes.megabytes(multiUploadConfig.getMaxFileSize()));
    }

    public static IUploadFileHandler getUploadFileHandler() {
        return _uploadFileHandler;
    }

    public static void setUploadFileHandler(IUploadFileHandler uploadFileHandler) {
        _uploadFileHandler = uploadFileHandler;
    }
```

I use `MyMultiFileUploadField` in a Wicket form which has the following HTML.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Upload form</legend>
    <p>
      <div wicket:id="fileInput" class="mfuex" />
    </p>
    <input wicket:id="submitUploads" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hello, where in the form you add the 'submitUploads' button ? Because I can not see it in the above code of the form. I use wicket 7.5 and when I run the above in my application I get a "ServletRequest does not contain multipart content. One possible solution is to explicitly call Form.setMultipart(true)" even if I have setMultiPart(true); to my form. Thank you

Comment: @GeorgePap I have a `public class FileUploadForm extends Form<Void> {` where, in the constructor I created a `new AjaxButton(id) {` in method `private AjaxButton createSubmitAjaxButton(String id) {`. I have also set that button as `submitUploads = createSubmitAjaxButton(BUTTON_SUBMIT); submitUploads.setMarkupId(markupIdPrefix + BUTTON_SUBMIT); setDefaultButton(submitUploads); add(submitUploads);` After that I `setMultiPart(true);` (also in the constructor). I hope this can help you solve your issue.