# Json Received data = null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Hi I have json request like here:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/DeviceUsage/FreeDevice",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: Ids }),
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error " + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === "") {
                alert("succes")
            }
            else {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });
```

where Ids = `var Ids = new Array();` ( full of ints)

My Json looks like this:

```
{"data":[38,40,41]}
```

method where I'm receiving Json:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FreeDevice(FreeDeviceModel m)
{
    return Json("");
}
```

and my ViewModel:

```
public class FreeDeviceModel
{
    public List<int> data { get; set; }
}
```

I cross checked everything with Json validator, Json2C#

and eveything looks correct so why nothing is reveived by the FreeDevice method?

For clarification I have problem with this :
[image: Data shoudl be List of 3 elements but is Null]

Data shoudl be List of 3 elements but is Null

Comment: I updated my question. I have in mind that freeDevice is not receiving anything

Comment: So the ajax call enter the condition where it alerts the data, right?

Comment: Ok I provided the screenshot of thing I have problemn with ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Below Code it should work

Json Call

```
var FreeDeviceModel = {};
FreeDeviceModel.data = new Array();
FreeDeviceModel.data[0] = 39;
FreeDeviceModel.data[1] = 40;
FreeDeviceModel.data[2] = 41;
var object = JSON.stringify({ FreeDeviceModel: FreeDeviceModel });
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/FreeDevice",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: object,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
     error: function (data) {
        alert("error " + data);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data === "") {
            alert("succes")
        }
        else {
            alert(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Controller Call

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FreeDevice(FreeDeviceModel FreeDeviceModel)
    {
        return Json("");
    }
```

Comment: Ok I accept this answer. You wrote same I wrote in my self answer ;) ContentType was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the dataType to JSON

```
dataType: 'json',
data: {"data":[38,40,41]}
```

Hope it helped...

Comment: Hard  coding the data is no the option ;)

Comment: i meant adding your json directly without using stringify and set the dataType to json :)

Comment: I know, Checked it but this gave no effect

Comment: guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168401/json-formatting-sending-json-via-jquery-ajax-post-to-java-wicket-server) will help you get it

Answer (score 0):

Ok. 
Adding this line:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

fixed everything!

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
public JsonResult FreeDevice(string details)
{
FreeDeviceModel tempRecord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FreeDeviceModel>>(details);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try:

```
data: JSON.stringify(Ids),
```

Comment: after this modification still null